# Recharts package won't install properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, vite, recharts

I installed rechart and recharts packages using a demo create react app just to play around with making a chart and it seemed to work fine. But when I try to download these packages into my React project that uses Vite I get these vulnerability messages.

```
# npm audit report

d3-color  <3.1.0
Severity: high
d3-color vulnerable to ReDoS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-36jr-mh4h-2g58
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install recharts@0.22.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/d3-color
  d3-interpolate  0.1.3 - 2.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-color
  node_modules/d3-interpolate
    d3-scale  0.1.5 - 3.3.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-interpolate
    node_modules/d3-scale
      recharts  >=0.2.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-interpolate
      Depends on vulnerable versions of d3-scale
      node_modules/recharts

lodash  <=4.17.20
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-jf85-cpcp-j695
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-x5rq-j2xg-h7qm
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-p6mc-m468-83gw
Prototype Pollution in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-fvqr-27wr-82fm
Command Injection in lodash - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-35jh-r3h4-6jhm
No fix available
node_modules/lodash
  rechart  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of lodash
  node_modules/rechart

6 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 4 high, 1 critical)

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

I tried using the `npm audit fix --force` that the terminal says but it does not work. I also tried uninstalling the packages and re-installing them which didn't work. Lastly, I tried deleting the node modules folder and running `npm i` again but still have the same problem.

Comment: You're using a really old version of recharts. The latest version is 2.1.16. Can you upgrade? The fix for that audit issue was made in 2020.

Comment: I ran 'npm update' but still get the exact same npm audit report.